# Having problems migrating in South

Tags: mysql, django, django-south

I am using mysql. On my local machine I have 3 migrations and on the server I have nearly 9. I pushed my code + migrations to github. Pulled it on the server.

used `./manage.py migrate appname`

It didn't work. Then I tried with a `--merge` Flag. It also didn't work! I am really new to dbms. Need help. Here `00008_merge_models` is an empty migration using `./manage.py schemamigration appname --empty merge_models` as given in the docs.

```
- Soft matched migration 0008 to 0008_merge_models.
Running migrations for appname:
 - Migrating forwards to 0008_merge_models.
 > appname:0002_auto__add_field_student_cv__add_field_student_status__chg_field_studen
FATAL ERROR - The following SQL query failed: ALTER TABLE `appname_student` ADD COLUMN `cv` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '';
The error was: (1060, "Duplicate column name 'cv'")
 ! Error found during real run of migration! Aborting.

 ! Since you have a database that does not support running
 ! schema-altering statements in transactions, we have had 
 ! to leave it in an interim state between migrations.

! You *might* be able to recover with:   - no dry run output for delete_foreign_key() due to dynamic DDL, sorry
   = ALTER TABLE `appname_student` DROP COLUMN `cv` CASCADE; []
   - no dry run output for delete_foreign_key() due to dynamic DDL, sorry
   = ALTER TABLE `appname_student` DROP COLUMN `status` CASCADE; []
   = DROP TABLE `appname_student_companyapplications` CASCADE; []
   = DROP TABLE `appname_student_placedat` CASCADE; []
   - no dry run output for alter_column() due to dynamic DDL, sorry
   - no dry run output for delete_foreign_key() due to dynamic DDL, sorry
   = ALTER TABLE `appname_job` DROP COLUMN `createdon` CASCADE; []
   - no dry run output for alter_column() due to dynamic DDL, sorry
   - no dry run output for alter_column() due to dynamic DDL, sorry
   - no dry run output for alter_column() due to dynamic DDL, sorry

 ! The South developers regret this has happened, and would
 ! like to gently persuade you to consider a slightly
 ! easier-to-deal-with DBMS (one that supports DDL transactions)
 ! NOTE: The error which caused the migration to fail is further up.
Error in migration: appname:0002_auto__add_field_student_cv__add_field_student_status__chg_field_studen
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/south/management/commands/migrate.py", line 111, in handle
    ignore_ghosts = ignore_ghosts,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/south/migration/__init__.py", line 220, in migrate_app
    success = migrator.migrate_many(target, workplan, database)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 254, in migrate_many
    result = migrator.__class__.migrate_many(migrator, target, migrations, database)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 329, in migrate_many
    result = self.migrate(migration, database)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 133, in migrate
    result = self.run(migration, database)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 114, in run
    return self.run_migration(migration, database)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 84, in run_migration
    migration_function()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 60, in <lambda>
    return (lambda: direction(orm))
  File "/home/byld/placement/placement/appname/migrations/0002_auto__add_field_student_cv__add_field_student_status__chg_field_studen.py", line 14, in forwards
    keep_default=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/south/db/generic.py", line 47, in _cache_clear
    return func(self, table, *args, **opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/south/db/generic.py", line 418, in add_column
    self.execute(sql)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/south/db/generic.py", line 282, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 69, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 124, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1060, "Duplicate column name 'cv'")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it didn't work on your server is that probably on your local machine you had different database ...

I would suggest to check what is in your sever database and what's in the `models.py`. When code in `models.py` will be equal to your database you can remove all migrations from server. Than simply use South again.

`python manage.py schemamigration app --initial`
`python manage.py migrate app`

Comment: What do you mean by different database?
models.py has an extra column that i want to add. I migrated the db on my local machine. migrated on the server. but the changes are not reflected in the db on the server due to this problem.

Comment: The problem is that your database on server differ from migrations on server ... Like I suggest comment all your new "extra columns" then remove migrations and use --initial

Comment: You mean extra columns from models.py?

Comment: remove everything from migrations foder. created an --initial migration. I commented out the xx field from the models.py. (xx is the field that i want to add to the db.). added another --auto migration which says 0002_auto__del_field_xx. migrated the app.  Gives an error FATAL ERROR - The following SQL query failed: ALTER TABLE `app_student` DROP COLUMN `xx` CASCADE;
The error was: (1091, "Can't DROP 'xx'; check that column/key exists")! Error found during real run of migration! Aborting.
! You might beable to recover with:=ALTER TABLE`app_student`ADD COLUMN`xx`varchar(3)NOTNULL DEFAULT '0';[]

Comment: Mate this is not such a hard thing... I did that same way few times.. Do you have much data in your server DB ? Maybe the better option would be to create a new DB

Comment: What is not a hard thing? Whatever you told me. Its not working.i cannot delete the db. Got a lot of stuff on it.